# Is there a way to make templated declaration

Tags: c++, templates

What I mean is modifying the following code, X declaration to be exact, so that I can use an object B of any kind, `B<int>`, `B<real>` ... Sadly, it's important I have an `Obj<T>` *pobj in B.

```
template <typename T>
class Obj
{
    public:
    T a;

    public:
    Obj(T a_) : a(a_) {}

    void print() const
    { std::cout << "a : " << a << std::endl; }

};


template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    Obj<T> *pObj;

    public:
   A(Obj<T>* pO) : pObj(pO) {}
    void doSomethingWithObj()
    { pObj->print(); }

    static Obj<double> X;
};

Obj<double> X = Obj<double>(1.0);


template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    public:
    B() : A<T>( &X ) {}

    void doSmthg()
    { X.print(); }
};

// in main
B<int> b;
b.doSmthg();
```

That code will return `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Obj<double>*’ to ‘Obj<int>*’`

Comment: `B<int>` derives from `A<int>` which in turn derives from `Obj<int>`. This is a completely different type than `X`, which is `Obj<double>`. That's why you cannot call `A<int>(*X)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might approach it like this:

```
struct ObjBase 
{
  virtual void print() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Obj : public ObjBase
{
    public:
    T a;

    public:
    Obj(T a_) : a(a_) {}

    virtual void print() const
    { std::cout << "a : " << a << std::endl; }

};

template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    ObjBase *pObj;

    public:
   A(ObjBase* pO) : pObj(pO) {}
    void doSomethingWithObj()
    { pObj->print(); }

    static Obj<double> X;
};
```

That is, have a base class that provides an interface for the things that you want to do that are not dependent on the particular type.

Comment: Type T is used for vectors, lengths precision in 3D space, so they all basically depend on the type. It can only be real or double, really.

Comment: @user2287453: Instead of having an `Obj<T>` pointer in `A<T>`, how about having an `Obj<T>` members which contains a copy of the value in X?

Comment: That will work and I guess that's what I'm going to use, but you guessed it, there are lots of objects B. All they really need is 1 model of X really so it feels like a waste.

Comment: oh right, after I did try it, I remembered the X I want to use to define B is actually a derived class of Obj .. So no..

Comment: That derived issue is fixed by keeping an Obj* in A but having an Obj member in B and sending its adress to A... I'm not happy with templates as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself.

It is ... I forgot the qualification in my tests..

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    Obj<T> *pObj;

    public:
   A(Obj<T>* pO) : pObj(pO) {}
    void doSomethingWithObj()
    { pObj->print(); }

    static Obj<T> X;
};

template<typename T>
Obj<T> Obj<T>::X(1.0);
```